# How fast is accessing a struct member in C?

Tags: c, performance, struct, micro-optimization

Is the process of accessing a struct member any slower than accessing a direct variable? If I have the same struct member used in multiple places, should I declare it in a variable and save it there to spare the cost of accessing the same member multiple times? Should I repeat `Struct.Member` `Struct.Member` `Struct.Member` or should I save it in a variable `int Member = Struct.Member` `Member` `Member` `Member`? At which point should I use the latter instead of the former? What if those members are bit fields?

Comment: I would go for convenience and readability. If you need more speed, use a better algorithm. If you really care about a few cycles here and there, measure. These things often defy naive intuition and you can make things worse in your quest to improve them.

Comment: To get to the point of the question, an optimizing compiler will usually recognize that those are the same thing and your two approaches may very well generate the same executable code. Just use what's more convenient.

Comment: **In most cases,** with a good optimizing compiler (e.g. some recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3`) **it should not matter at all**.

Comment: Short answer, No. Struct access is simply access at an address plus offset, no different than accessing an element in an array. Saving to a second variable would simply add that step to the process.

Answer (score 6):

While there are some complications involving accessing a structure member versus allocating a “direct” object, a more important difference in your scenario is that a compiler may be able to better optimize uses of a local variable than uses of a member of a structure it is passed.

This is because structures are commonly passed indirectly, by a pointer (that is either a parameter or a pointer from another structure). Consider this code:

```
struct S { int a; };

void baz(int);

void foo(struct S *s)
{
    baz(s->a);
    baz(s->a);
}

void bar(struct S *s)
{
    int a = s->a;
    baz(a);
    baz(a);
}
```

In `bar`, the compiler knows that `baz` cannot change `a`, because `a` is a local variable whose address is never taken. Therefore, the compiler can load `s->a` from memory once and pass it to `baz` twice.

In `foo`, the compiler cannot know that `baz` does not change `s->a`, because `baz` could have some way of accessing `s->a` such as through an address stored in an external object. Therefore, it has to load `s->a` before the first call to `baz` and again between the first call and the second call.

Testing with Apple Clang 11.0.0 with optimization enabled confirms this; the assembly code generated for the `foo` routine contains two loads of `s->a` from memory, while the code for `bar` contains only one.

Although this occurs frequently for structures since structures are commonly passed by address, this is not inherently a consequence of being a structure member. The same issue occurs in this code:

```
void baz(int);

void foo(int *p)
{
    baz(*p);
    baz(*p);
}

void bar(int *p)
{
    int a = *p;
    baz(a);
    baz(a);
}
```

It can also occur even if no subroutine is called; parameters can “interfere” with other parameters. In the following code, `foo` must reload `z->a` but `bar` does not need to. Even though `z` is qualified with `const`, the assignment to `x` might change it:

```
struct S { int a; };

void foo(struct S *x, struct S *y, const struct S *z)
{
    x->a = z->a;
    y->a = z->a;
}

void bar(struct S *x, struct S *y, const struct S *z)
{
    int a = z->a;
    x->a = a;
    y->a = a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why a struct member access would be slower than a plain variable.

There might be a few special case exceptions to that, like when you have a pointer to struct, and the compiler has to go through the pointer to get to the data. Then you get indirect access, which is generally a tiny bit slower than direct access. But micro-optimizations like that isn't something you should worry about when writing code.

Generally, focus on writing readable code and you usually get fast code at the same time. Beginners trying to manually optimize code and thereby turning it into an unholy mess is a common problem. Manual code optimization is very qualified work and not something you should be worrying about until you have some 10+ years of programming experience.

Comment: A pointer to a struct is no slower than a pointer to a scalar object.  The only thing I'd say is that having your local vars spread out across a few members you actually access out of multiple large structs decreases spatial locality for the data you touch.  But for only a few named vars that's not worth extra copying; compilers will keep them in registers.  (Although copying global data once to a private local can help compilers keep something in registers, depending on escape analysis / alias analysis.  Especially with indirection `int local = ptr->member;` may sometimes help.)

Comment: (Of course, if the compiler keeps a few frequently-accessed values in registers, which it will for back-to-back accesses, locality stops mattering after the first fetch.  It's typically only across non-inline function calls or large amounts of other code that they might have to get reloaded from their original locations.)

Comment: What about bit fields?

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant to say that a pointer to struct is slower than direct access. That is `void f (struct foo* f) { int x = f->bar; }` is very likely a tiny bit slower than `void f (int foo) { int x = foo; }`.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers No difference there either, except that using bit fields might enforce padding that takes up extra memory.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: bitfield members are somewhat slower to read and modify when the access can't be optimized away, if they aren't a whole number of bytes aligned on a byte boundary.  e.g. 4x `:8` fields of an int should be no slower than a `char [4]`, but 2x `:5` is worse. But when the as-if rule can prove that one "real" access to memory and unpack is sufficient, that's all the compiler will do in asm.  If you're curious, check the asm output to see how much (if any) extra work the compiler is doing: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: @PeterCordes How about a `:5` and `:3`?

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: That will align the *next* field to a byte boundary, and if you're writing both member together then the compiler can hopefully AND + shift / OR together the 2 values into a byte and only have to do a store, instead of loading the old value.  The fact that the `:3` member ends at a byte boundary may help save an AND instruction, e.g. the compiler can load it with a zero- or sign-extending byte load (depending on bitfield signedness), and just right-shift by 5 to get the 3-bit value extended into a full register (`int` or `long`).  Especially helpful for signed bitfields.

Comment: What this whole discussion boils down to is that manual optimization has to be done on _case to case basis_, for a specific system.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: https://godbolt.org/z/GTceoK shows GCC and clang for x86-64, ARM and AArch64.  Clang especially does some pretty clever stuff like I suggested would be possible.  GCC misses some of the optimizations, but still ending at the top of a byte helps it some.  It also shows that in the general case, *modifying* a bitfield is not very efficient, especially on ISAs without good bitfield instructions like x86.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that in using GNU C and writing code to a Cortex M33 using the highest available optimization setting, pulling a value out of an array before using it in a 'for' loop saved a few cycles. I would expect that the compiler treats a structure much like an array, so it probably would likewise speed things up, but very slightly.

The code I'm writing must execute AFAP so I measure everything. Measuring is probably the only way to know for sure. Beware when measuring code with high optimization settings though. If you test something where the result is going nowhere, the optimizer will often not bother running the inner loops. I use a scope and an IO pin to measure timing. Making the IO state depend on the result solves this problem... usually ;)

Comment: If you mean `int tmp = arr[idx];` manual hoisting of a load, that's probably because the compiler couldn't prove that stores in the loop didn't alias that array position, and thus had to actually reload that array element each iteration.  (i.e. alias analysis, sometimes helped by `int *restrict ptr`.)  If you only had a pointer to a struct, you could easily have the same effect.  But if you had a local struct and you hadn't passed the address to anything, the optimizer can prove that no other pointers could be pointing into that struct.  (This is called "escape analysis").